# Detect device over Point Resolutions

Tags: ios, xcode

I created an view with 6 buttons, the problem was that when I was rotating to landscape the graphical result was not good.

Should look like this: loghos.eu/hoch.png
loghos.eu/quer.png

After some research I saw this script: [Link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_4_iPad_Rotation,_View_Resizing_and_Layout_Handling_(Xcode_4))

I tried to manage this with the point resolution from the iPhone.
But it doesn't work

```
    - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    #define IS_IPHONE_5 ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
    #define IS_IPHONE_6_Plus ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 736)
    if( IS_IPHONE_6_Plus )
    {
        if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
            toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        {
            eins.frame = CGRectMake(40, 75, 115, 115);
            zwei.frame = CGRectMake(530, 75, 115, 115);
            drei.frame = CGRectMake(290, 75, 115, 115);
            vier.frame = CGRectMake(290, 230, 115, 115);
            fuenf.frame = CGRectMake(40, 230, 115, 115);
            sechs.frame = CGRectMake(530, 230, 115, 115);
        }
        else
        {
            eins.frame = CGRectMake(30, 95, 115, 115);
            zwei.frame = CGRectMake(250, 95, 115, 115);
            drei.frame = CGRectMake(30, 300, 115, 115);
            vier.frame = CGRectMake(250, 300, 115, 115);
            fuenf.frame = CGRectMake(30, 530, 115, 115);
            sechs.frame = CGRectMake(250, 530, 115, 115);
        }
    }

    if( IS_IPHONE_5 )
    {
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
        toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        eins.frame = CGRectMake(40, 75, 115, 115);
        zwei.frame = CGRectMake(530, 75, 115, 115);
        drei.frame = CGRectMake(290, 75, 115, 115);
        vier.frame = CGRectMake(290, 230, 115, 115);
        fuenf.frame = CGRectMake(40, 230, 115, 115);
        sechs.frame = CGRectMake(530, 230, 115, 115);
    }
    else
    {
        eins.frame = CGRectMake(30, 95, 115, 115);
        zwei.frame = CGRectMake(190, 95, 115, 115);
        drei.frame = CGRectMake(30, 220, 115, 115);
        vier.frame = CGRectMake(190, 220, 115, 115);
        fuenf.frame = CGRectMake(30, 330, 115, 115);
        sechs.frame = CGRectMake(190, 330, 115, 115);
    }
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you attach your images again?  They don't appear to be attached correctly.

Comment: http://www.loghos.eu/hoch.png

Comment: http://www.loghos.eu/quer.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is *very* bad practice to hard code button frames like that, based on device.  Instead, your goal should be to create an interface that adapts to whatever size it is in either through autolayout or your own math.

I would recommend using `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to layout your views correctly.  This method is automatically called when rotation occurs since the view must be laid out again.  From there, you can detect the size class of the view if you're on iOS 8 or fall back to detecting the interface orientation on iOS 7.

Here's an example of what your `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method could look like:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {

    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    // first decide whether we are landscape

    BOOL isLandscape = NO;
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(traitCollection)]) {

        if ([[self traitCollection] verticalSizeClass] == UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact) {

            isLandscape = YES;

        }

    } else {

        if ([self interfaceOrientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [self interfaceOrientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

            isLandscape = YES;

        }

    }

    // now layout the views depending on if it is landscape or not

    CGFloat const buttonSize = 115;
    if (isLandscape) {

        CGFloat const columnWidth = CGRectGetWidth([[self view] bounds]) / 3.0;
        CGFloat const leftColumnX = (columnWidth - buttonSize) / 2.0;
        CGFloat const middleColumnX = columnWidth + leftColumnX;
        CGFloat const rightColumnX = columnWidth * 2 + leftColumnX;

        CGFloat const rowHeight = CGRectGetHeight([[self view] bounds]) / 2.0;
        CGFloat const topRowY = (rowHeight - buttonSize) / 2.0;
        CGFloat const bottomRowY = rowHeight + topRowY;

        [[self viewOne] setFrame:CGRectMake(leftColumnX, topRowY, buttonSize, buttonSize)];
        [[self viewTwo] setFrame:CGRectMake(middleColumnX, topRowY, buttonSize, buttonSize)];
        [[self viewThree] setFrame:CGRectMake(rightColumnX, topRowY, buttonSize, buttonSize)];
        [[self viewFour] setFrame:CGRectMake(leftColumnX, bottomRowY, buttonSize, buttonSize)];
        [[self viewFive] setFrame:CGRectMake(middleColumnX, bottomRowY, buttonSize, buttonSize)];
        [[self viewSix] setFrame:CGRectMake(rightColumnX, bottomRowY, buttonSize, buttonSize)];

    } else {

        CGFloat const columnWidth = CGRectGetWidth([[self view] bounds]) / 2.0;
        CGFloat const leftColumnX = (columnWidth - buttonSize) / 2.0;
        CGFloat const rightColumnX = columnWidth + leftColumnX;

        CGFloat const rowHeight = CGRectGetHeight([[self view] bounds]) / 3.0;
        CGFloat const topRowY = (rowHeight - buttonSize) / 2.0;
        CGFloat const middleRowY = rowHeight + topRowY;
        CGFloat const bottomRowY = rowHeight * 2 + topRowY;

        [[self viewOne] setFrame:CGRectMake(leftColumnX, topRowY, buttonSize, buttonSize)];
        [[self viewTwo] setFrame:CGRectMake(rightColumnX, topRowY, buttonSize, buttonSize)];
        [[self viewThree] setFrame:CGRectMake(leftColumnX, middleRowY, buttonSize, buttonSize)];
        [[self viewFour] setFrame:CGRectMake(rightColumnX, middleRowY, buttonSize, buttonSize)];
        [[self viewFive] setFrame:CGRectMake(leftColumnX, bottomRowY, buttonSize, buttonSize)];
        [[self viewSix] setFrame:CGRectMake(rightColumnX, bottomRowY, buttonSize, buttonSize)];

    }

}
```

From here, your views will layout correctly on any device since the layout is dependent on the width and height of the view bounds.  Here's some screenshots:

iPhone 4:

[image: iPhone 4 Portrait]
[image: iPhone 4 Landscape]

iPhone 5:

[image: iPhone 5 Portrait]
[image: iPhone 5 Landscape]

iPhone 6+:

[image: iPhone 6+ Portrait]
[image: iPhone 6+ Landscape]

Comment: Sry, I have one more question, how can I set the height from the top?

Comment: Right now it will automatically fill the full screen size evenly.  To set the height from the top you'd have to offset the row y values and then subtract the offset from the `rowHeight` variable.  Takes a little math to setup correctly.